# Discover the charset from foreign database

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have mysql database (not mine). In this database all the encodings set to utf-8, and I connect with charset utf-8. But, when I try to read from the database I get this:

```
×¢×?×§ 1
×‘×™×ª ×ª×•×’× ×” ×”×¢×•×¡×§ ×‘×ž×¡×¤×¨ ×©×¤×•×ª ×ª×•×›× ×” 
× × ×œ× ×œ×¤× ×•×ª ××—×¨×™ 12 ×‘×œ×™×œ×” ..
```

What I supposed to get:

```
עסק 1
בית תוגנה העוסק במספר שפות תוכנה
נא לא לפנות אחרי 12 בלילה ..
```

When I look from phpmyadmin, I have the same thing(connection in pma is to utf-8).
I know that the data is supposed to be in Hebrew.  Someone have an idea how to fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have UTF-8 data that was treated as Windows-1252 and subsequently converted to UTF-8 (sometimes referred to as "double-encoding").

The first thing that you need to determine is at what stage the conversion took place: before the data was saved in the table, or upon your attempts to retrieve it?  The easiest way is often to `SELECT HEX(the_column) FROM the_table WHERE ...` and manually inspect the byte-encoding as it is currently stored:

- If, for the data above, you see `C397C2A9...` then the data is stored erroneously (an incorrect [connection character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) at the time of data insertion is the most common culprit); it can be corrected as follows (being careful to use data types of sufficient length in place of `TEXT` and `BLOB` as appropriate):

  1. Undo the conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 that caused the data corruption:

     ```sql
     ALTER TABLE the_table MODIFY the_column TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1;
     ```
  2. Drop the erroneous encoding metadata:

     ```sql
     ALTER TABLE the_table MODIFY the_column BLOB;
     ```
  3. Add corrected encoding metadata:

     ```sql
     ALTER TABLE the_table MODIFY the_column TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
     ```

  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/080cd/1/0).

  Beware to correctly insert any data in the future, or else the table will be partly encoded in one way and partly in another (which can be a nightmare to try and fix).

  If you're unable to modify the database schema, the records can be transcoded to the correct encoding on-the-fly with `CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(the_column USING latin1) USING utf8)` (see it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eee49/1)), but I strongly recommended that you fix the database when possible instead of leaving it containing broken data.
- However, if you see `D7A2D73F...` then the data is stored correctly and the corruption is taking place upon data retrieval; you will have to perform further tests to identify the exact cause.  See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279) for guidance.

Comment: Another qustion. How i do these in php? I tried $a = iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $a); and it worked, but when I use htmlspecialchars, it says "Invalid multibyte sequence in argument", and I specify utf-8 charset in htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @Kirill: I think you should probably [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), detailing what you are trying to accomplish and what you are seeing instead.

Comment: I want to read from database correctly without changing it, because it isn't my database, and I don't sure I will have the permission to change it. So I want to correct the text in php, I tried to do these with iconv, but i had the problem that i described above.

Comment: @Kirill: I covered this possibility in the most recent edit to my answer above.  See the paragraph beginning "*If you're unable to modify the database schema...*".  Another possibility would be to deliberately set an erroneous connection character set, but that might break other things and will only exacerbate problems for the future.